# How to skips model dirty checking with $http?

Tags: angularjs, binding

You can skip model dirty checking in `$timeout` service by setting the third parameter called `invokeApply` to `false` (see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout)).

Is it possible to achieve the same result with the `$http` service?

I need to call a legacy third-party restful webservice several times, but must reduce the amount of refreshes on the UI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use jQuery.ajax or any other ajax library to make http requests out of the digest loop.

In fact, $http will not send any request outside the digest loop. This is from the angular comments:

> The `$http` service will not actually send the request until the next `$digest()` is
>        executed. Normally this is not an issue, since almost all the time your call to `$http` will
>        be from within a `$apply()` block.
>        If you are calling `$http` from outside Angular, then you should wrap it in a call to
>        `$apply` to cause a $digest to occur and also to handle errors in the block correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I used jQuery.ajax as a first solution. I will try to extend `$http` to support this feature, so that the syntax remains the same.

Comment: @jeromerg you ever extend $http?

Comment: @Langdon actually, if I remember well, I didn't extend it... it's 1,5 years ago... ;-)

Comment: @jeromerg haha, it is, I know.. and somehow the issue is still outstanding. =/  it's become a performance issue for me since I'm polling and not using web sockets.  tracking a hopeful official fix here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2049